# CMAKE Qt5 error: ‘AA_EnableHighDpiScaling’ is not a member of ‘Qt’

Tags: cmake, qt5

I am trying to build project which uses QT5  with  CMAKE.

I have got CMakeLists.txt  like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)

project(uidraft)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS  Widgets Core Gui Qml Quick REQUIRED)
```

also instead of this find_package I tried:

```
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Quick)
find_package(Qt5Qml)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Gui)
```

And I always get error:

```
error: ‘AA_EnableHighDpiScaling’ is not a member of ‘Qt’
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

Part from main.cpp with this code:

```
QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
//QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

Guys, what is wrong?  How to build it with cmake? Which library or parameter I missed?

Comment: Thank you. It was root cause of this issue.  It have built  after I had set path to Qt 5.6 instead of Qt 5.5 ( which providing in Ubuntu 16.04 by default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt 5.x isn't enough. Verify you are using at least Qt 5.6 (version since which the value has been introduced, according to the documentation). Otherwise it's not available, the compiler is right.